How to make pip virtual environments truly portable?
I'm trying to install Open WebUI as a portable installation, where the base folder can be moved or renamed. However, I've encountered issues making the virtual environment truly portable.
While installing, I've tried using dynamic paths, but somehow the paths get hardcoded during the installation process. When I try to activate the virtual environment in a different location, I receive an error:
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"...original\path\venv\Scripts\python.exe"  "...new\path\venv\Scripts\open-webui.exe" serve': The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I solve this issue and make my pip virtual environments truly portable?
In this example I'm using two batch files to install Open WebUI.
setup.bat
@echo on
REM setup.bat - Run this first to create the Open-WebUI_portable environment
set BASE_DIR=%~dp0
set VENV_DIR=%BASE_DIR%venv
set PYTHON_DIR=%BASE_DIR%python
set PIP_DIR=%BASE_DIR%pip-cache
set APPDATA=%BASE_DIR%appdata
set USERPROFILE=%BASE_DIR%userprofile
set HOME=%BASE_DIR%home
set XDG_CACHE_HOME=%BASE_DIR%cache
set PYTHONUSERBASE=%BASE_DIR%pythonuser

echo Creating directories...
mkdir "%PIP_DIR%" 2>nul
mkdir "%APPDATA%" 2>nul
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%" 2>nul
mkdir "%HOME%" 2>nul
mkdir "%XDG_CACHE_HOME%" 2>nul
mkdir "%PYTHONUSERBASE%" 2>nul

:DOWNLOAD_PYTHON
echo Downloading Python...
curl -L "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.8/python-3.11.8-embed-amd64.zip" -o "%BASE_DIR%python.zip"
if not exist "%BASE_DIR%python.zip" (
    echo ERROR: Failed to download Python
    echo Would you like to retry? (Y/N^)
    choice /c yn /n
    if errorlevel 2 (
        echo Installation cancelled
        exit /b 1
    )
    goto DOWNLOAD_PYTHON
)

echo Extracting Python...
powershell -Command "Expand-Archive -Path '%BASE_DIR%python.zip' -DestinationPath '%PYTHON_DIR%' -Force"
if not exist "%PYTHON_DIR%\python.exe" (
    echo ERROR: Failed to extract Python
    pause
    exit /b 1
)

echo Configuring Python for pip...
del "%PYTHON_DIR%\python311._pth" 2>nul
(
echo python311.zip
echo .
echo %PYTHON_DIR%\Lib\site-packages
echo .
echo import site
) > "%PYTHON_DIR%\python311._pth"

:DOWNLOAD_GETPIP
echo Downloading get-pip.py...
curl -L "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "%BASE_DIR%get-pip.py"
if not exist "%BASE_DIR%get-pip.py" (
    echo ERROR: Failed to download get-pip.py
    echo You can try to download it manually from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    echo and place it in %BASE_DIR%get-pip.py
    echo.
    echo Would you like to retry the download? (Y/N^)
    choice /c yn /n
    if errorlevel 2 (
        echo Installation cancelled
        exit /b 1
    )
    goto DOWNLOAD_GETPIP
)

echo Installing pip...
"%PYTHON_DIR%\python.exe" "%BASE_DIR%get-pip.py" --no-warn-script-location
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ERROR: Failed to install pip
    echo This is a critical error. Please ensure:
    echo 1. You have internet connection
    echo 2. Any antivirus is not blocking the installation
    echo 3. You are running this script as administrator
    pause
    exit /b 1
)

echo Installing virtualenv...
"%PYTHON_DIR%\Scripts\pip.exe" install virtualenv
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ERROR: Failed to install virtualenv
    echo This is a critical error. Please check your internet connection
    pause
    exit /b 1
)

echo Creating virtual environment...
"%PYTHON_DIR%\Scripts\virtualenv.exe" "%VENV_DIR%"
if not exist "%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\activate.bat" (
    echo ERROR: Failed to create virtual environment
    pause
    exit /b 1
)

echo Installing Open WebUI...
call "%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\activate.bat"
"%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\pip.exe" install --cache-dir="%PIP_DIR%" open-webui
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ERROR: Failed to install Open WebUI
    pause
    exit /b 1
)

echo Creating postactivate script for relocatable paths...
mkdir "%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\postactivate.d" 2>nul
(
echo @echo on
echo set BASE_DIR=%%~dp0
echo set APPDATA=%%BASE_DIR%%appdata
echo set LOCALAPPDATA=%%BASE_DIR%%localappdata
echo set USERPROFILE=%%BASE_DIR%%userprofile
echo set HOME=%%BASE_DIR%%home
echo set XDG_CACHE_HOME=%%BASE_DIR%%cache
echo set XDG_CONFIG_HOME=%%BASE_DIR%%config
echo set PYTHONUSERBASE=%%BASE_DIR%%pythonuser
echo set PIP_CACHE_DIR=%%BASE_DIR%%pip-cache
echo set TEMP=%%BASE_DIR%%temp
echo set TMP=%%BASE_DIR%%temp
) > "%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\postactivate.d\relocatable.bat"

echo Cleaning up...
del "%BASE_DIR%python.zip"
del "%BASE_DIR%get-pip.py"

echo Setup complete! Use run.bat to start Open WebUI
pause

and run.bat
@echo on
set BASE_DIR=%~dp0
set VENV_DIR=%BASE_DIR%venv

REM Set all environment variables to keep files in Open-WebUI_portable directory
set APPDATA=%BASE_DIR%appdata
set LOCALAPPDATA=%BASE_DIR%localappdata
set USERPROFILE=%BASE_DIR%userprofile
set HOME=%BASE_DIR%home
set XDG_CACHE_HOME=%BASE_DIR%cache
set XDG_CONFIG_HOME=%BASE_DIR%config
set PYTHONUSERBASE=%BASE_DIR%pythonuser
set PIP_CACHE_DIR=%BASE_DIR%pip-cache
set TEMP=%BASE_DIR%temp
set TMP=%BASE_DIR%temp

REM Create necessary directories
mkdir "%APPDATA%" 2>nul
mkdir "%LOCALAPPDATA%" 2>nul
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%" 2>nul
mkdir "%HOME%" 2>nul
mkdir "%XDG_CACHE_HOME%" 2>nul
mkdir "%XDG_CONFIG_HOME%" 2>nul
mkdir "%PYTHONUSERBASE%" 2>nul
mkdir "%TEMP%" 2>nul


REM Activate virtual environment
call "%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\activate.bat"

REM Run postactivate script for relocatable paths
call "%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\postactivate.d\relocatable.bat"

REM Run Open WebUI
"%VENV_DIR%\Scripts\open-webui.exe" serve

REM Open browser to localhost:8080
start "" http://localhost:8080

pause

It initially works fine, but when I rename or move the base folder it stops working.
Error:
F:\OpenWebUI-portable-NEW>call "F:\OpenWebUI-portable-NEW\venv\Scripts\activate.bat"
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"F:\OpenWebUI-portable-OLD\venv\Scripts\python.exe"  "F:\OpenWebUI-portable-NEW\venv\Scripts\open-webui.exe" serve': The system cannot find the file specified.


IMO you don't want venvs portable, it defeats the essence of venvs in the first place. The idea behind venvs is to have an isolated environment to manage projects that requires specific versions of packages. Thankfully venvs can easily be destroyed and recreated and if you have your requirements.txt, pip install -r requirements.txt into the new venv.

thank you for your comment, it makes sense. But I really do want to make a portable installation, since I need to move it often. What do you suggest?

Is moving it often the main issue or setting your environment variables?

If I move an app between two environments, all I need do is python -m venv .venv and activate with .venv\scripts\activate. This seems very easy to me. In the active venv, I'll run pip install -r requirements.txt to install the packages listed in requirements.txt. Then of course I have environment variables stored in a .env file and retrieved using a package like python-dotenv. This whole process seems very easy for me even if in switching multiple environments.

I'll need to try it out. But I've found another way, if I delete the python and venv folder, and use setup.bat, it'll use the cache files to reinstall everything. since it doesn't require an internet connection or existing python installation, might be useful

According to the docs:

A virtual environment is (amongst other things):

Used to contain a specific Python interpreter and software libraries and binaries which are needed to support a project (library or application). These are by default isolated from software in other virtual environments and Python interpreters and libraries installed in the operating system.
Contained in a directory, conventionally named .venv or venv in the project directory, or under a container directory for lots of virtual environments, such as ~/.virtualenvs.
Not checked into source control systems such as Git.




Considered as disposable – it should be simple to delete and recreate it from scratch. You don’t place any project code in the environment.
Not considered as movable or copyable – you just recreate the same environment in the target location.


However I found this package venvctl which is used to create portable virtual environments programmatically (Haven't tested this so use at your own risk).
Also I don't know whether the answers here are helpful to you although there's no accepted answer.
Just to emphasize that my position is that of the docs and stated in the comments.

venvctl isn't working, keep getting errors related to pyproject.toml.
Errors are like this:
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1

Again I haven't used this package but from the information on PyPI, it supports Python 3.6 - 3.9. If you're using a newer version of Python, you can downgrade to python 3.9

Open WebUI doesn't work below 3.11, and since the normal venv won't be movable anyway. so, is there any other way to make a installation like this portable?

Have a look at https://pypi.org/project/venv-pack2/ and https://github.com/hmasdev/penv

i got errors after environment gets packed, and I think Open WebUI won't function well with venv-pack, since it creates a huge venv folder.
so far the workaround to create offline portable project folder is this:
In case of after moving or renaming the installation folder stops working, do the following:
empty these folders: python, venv

setup.bat
copy-paste the following files and folders:


telemetry_user_id
webui.db
vector_db
uploads


run.bat
import necessary files if needed


if this works for you, and you feel it answers your question, feel free to post as answer and accept it.
